# What are word combinations similar to the effect of "Sofa King" called?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a name for word combination structures that embed other words within them (both verbal or written)? (Any less rude example would be appreciated.)

Comment: "Anyone for coffee?"

Comment: Can you give more detailsnof what you are thinking of? More examples? It is not clear what you mean by 'sofa king'. Two nouns in a row? What is the embedded word or meaning in 'sofa king'? It is not obvious.

Comment: @Mitch: Sofa King -> So f**king

Comment: I ended up here looking for the same answer. Another example if it hasn't been mentioned yet is Sandy Eggo
Or the name Heywood U. Blowmie.

Comment: Paul Nurse and Richard Sole, and my fave, the Foo King Twat

Comment: Captain Pugwash and Seaman Staines deserve a mention also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Wikipedia*’s definition of a “[deliberate mondegreen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen#Deliberate_mondegreen)” matches your example. As Bob [says](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/56219/5558), this is a [double entendre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_entendre). A deliberate mondegreen is a sub-species of double entendre that exploits [homophony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone) to get across its second meaning.

Answer (score 6):

This is called a *[double entendre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_entendre)*, wherein a spoken phrase is devised to be understood in more than one way. You’d typically call something like “sofa king” a *[gag name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gag_name)*, a false name meant to elicit humor either through some sort of double entendre or pun.

In many cases (such as your own), it’s a rather vulgar type of humor. For example, it was popular in the naming of “Bond girls” in James Bond films:

- Bibi Dahl from *For Your Eyes Only*
- Holly Goodhead from *Moonraker*
- Chu Mei from *The Man with the Golden Gun*
- Pussy Galore from *Goldenfinger*

Even spoofs like the Austin Powers movies caught on with names like Alotta Fagina in *Austin Powers: International Man of Mystery*.

Comment: And yes, I am a fan of spy shows and explicit humor.

Comment: If these punny names are double entendres, they're not the first kind of double entendre most people would think of. A double entendre is a phrase intended to mean one thing, that can be interpreted as another, usually risque, thing. "She was in the workshop looking for a screw, so I gave her one"

Comment: "A double entendre is a phrase intended to mean one thing, that can be interpreted as another, usually risque, thing."  So for example, "Sofa King."

Answer (score 4):

These are puns. They are a specific kind of pun, but I don't believe there is a special word for that kind of pun alone.

The British satirical magazine *Private Eye* runs letters with assumed names that can be read as words, and that section is titled *Pseudo Names*.

> *... I keep sending you examples of witty names that I keep making up, but you never print them. Am I wasting my time?*
>
> NOAH VALE